# ReactJS material-ui 'TypeError: onSelect is not a function' tabHandler

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Good day. I'm expectin a wierd error when trying to change tabs. Code seems okay. What am i missing? The point is to switch tabes based from what the user clicks. Tested out with `console.log` , it returns the correct value and raises this exception.

**App.js**

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            exerciseList: exercises,
            // category: 'chest'
        };
        // this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this)
    }

    onSelect = category => {
      this.setState({
          // console.log(category);
          category
      })
    };


    render() {
        const exercises = this.getExercisesByMuscles(),
            { category } = this.state;
        return (
            <Fragment>


                <Footer
                    category={category}
                    muscles={muscles}
                    onChange={this.onSelect}
                />

            </Fragment>


        );
    }
}
```

**Footer.js**

```
export default ({ muscles, category , onSelect }) => {
    const index = category ? muscles.findIndex(group => group === category) + 1
        : 0;


    return (
        <Paper >
            <Tabs
                value={index}
                onChange={(e, index) => {
                    onSelect(index === 0 ? '' : muscles[index] )
                }}
                indicatorColor="primary"
                textColor="primary"
                centered
            >
                <Tab label="All"/>
                {muscles.map(group =>
                    <Tab label={group}/>
                )}
            </Tabs>
        </Paper>
    )
}
```

Error happens when switching tabs. Error points to `onChange` function.

Comment: You aren't passing `Footer` a prop called `onSelect`, you're passing it one called `onChange`.

Comment: @BrianThompson can't quite get where you pointing at. I'm sending `onSelect`, arent i? ....

Comment: @BrianThompson Thanks, got it figured out.